# C# UserControl keyboard short cuts

Tags: c#, user-controls, keyboard-shortcuts

I've created a user control which has multiple textboxes, comboboxes etc.  The user control is hosted on a normal form.  I would like to assign keyboard short cuts to the text boxes, comboboxes.  So that when Ctrl + F are pressed together the focus is placed on the one of the text boxes.  I've tried using the OnPreviewKeyDown to examine the keys and then fire the key down method on the user control.  The debugger doesn't even hit the OnPreviewKeyDown method on the form.  I've enabled keyPreview on the form to be true.  I've provided some of my experiments below.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?  I can't believe something like this is so difficult.  I must be missing something simple.  Thanks

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        Keys k = e.KeyCode;

        UserControl1.UserControl_KeyPress(k);
    }

    public void UserControl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 'F')
            tbxHostName.Focus();

        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.F:
                this.cmbxProtocol.Focus();
                break;
            case Keys.H:
                this.tbxHostName.Focus();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know thtat focus is on the UserControl?
Otherwize you may have to handle the key events in the form and make that code select the text area in the user control.

Comment: Indicate if this is WPF or Winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend trying the [KeyDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx).  It takes in a [KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx) parameter, which includes a boolean specifically for the Ctrl key ([KeyEventArgs.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.control.aspx)).

In your case, you would compare the [KeyCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode.aspx) property to [Keys.F](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) to see if `F` was pressed, and check if `Control` was true.  For example:

```
public void UserControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Control)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode) 
        { 
            case Keys.F: 
                this.cmbxProtocol.Focus(); 
                break; 
            // Other cases ...
            default: 
                break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Alternately, if you really want to stick with your `KeyPress` event, you could check the value of the static [Control.ModifierKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys.aspx) property and see if the Ctrl key is pressed, like so:

```
if( (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control )
{
    //...
}
```